# Pandas Groupby and apply a custom function to each N- rows of a Column in that group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, and i want to perform a groupby  over a column and apply a custom function to another column. But that function has to be applied over every two entries of the apply-column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'vals':['ANZ', 'ABC', 'SAT', 'SATYA', 'SQL', 'WER', 'DEA', 'KIP', 'FTY', 'TCZ'] })
#df
id  vals  
1   ANZ
1   ABC
2   SAT
2   SATYA
2   SQL
3   WER
3   DEA
3   KIP
3   FTY
3   TCZ
# i need a column "res", as a func applied to column vals's each two rows on a group by on column 'id'. ### myfunc takes two argument and return one value.
df['res'] = df.groupby('id')['vals'].apply(myfunc)
###df
id  vals   res
1   ANZ    myfunc(None, ANZ)
1   ABC    myfunc('ANZ', 'ABC')
2   SAT    myfunc(None, 'SAT')
2   SATYA  myfunc('SAT', 'SATYA')
2   SQL    myfunc('SATYA', 'SQL')
3   WER    myfunc(None, 'WER')
3   DEA    myfunc('WER', 'DEA')
3   KIP    myfunc('DEA', 'KIP')
3   FTY    myfunc('KIP', 'FTY')
3   TCZ    myfunc('FTY', 'TCZ')
```

But currently not able to form the expression for apply(), as fora group by .apply(x), x will be a series and i am unable to find a way to use index wise access on x(pandas groupby series object).

Please guide me on how to achieve this, Thanks in Adv.

Comment: I have modified the code a little, please do have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So i tried out something like below.

Myfunc is used to find string similarity between two string, i used the awesome fuzzywuzzy library for that

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def myfunc(x):
    x = x.tolist() # converted series to list
    y = []
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        if i == 0:
            y.append(None)
        else:
            ## apply ratio between prev_Row_vals and Current_Row_vals
            y.append(fuzz.token_set_ratio(x[i - 1], x[i]) / 10)
    return y

  ## Now the group by and apply/transform function
  df['res'] = df.groupby('id')['vals'].transform(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

But i am not sure if it is the pythonic way to do such thing. Please do let me know if there is more pythonic way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try the below;

```
df['new_value']=df.vals.shift()
df.groupby(df.index//2)['vals','new_value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(zip(x.new_value,x.vals))))\
.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0      (nan, ANZ)
1      (ANZ, ABC)
2      (ABC, SAT)
3    (SAT, SATYA)
4    (SATYA, SQL)
5      (SQL, WER)
6      (WER, DEA)
7      (DEA, KIP)
8      (KIP, FTY)
9      (FTY, TCZ)
```

**EDIT** Modifying the code a little to match the output :

```
a=df.groupby('id')['vals'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x.shift(),x))))
df['new']=list(zip(a[0],a[1]))
print(df)

   id   vals           new
0   1    ANZ    (nan, ANZ)
1   1    ABC    (ANZ, ABC)
2   2    SAT    (nan, SAT)
3   2  SATYA  (SAT, SATYA)
4   2    SQL  (SATYA, SQL)
5   3    WER    (nan, WER)
6   3    DEA    (WER, DEA)
7   3    KIP    (DEA, KIP)
8   3    FTY    (KIP, FTY)
9   3    TCZ    (FTY, TCZ)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose to do your task slightly other way.

Start from generating a column with `vals` from the previous row
in the current group. I named it `prev`.

Then call your function using `apply` to each row in `df`, substituting
the result do `res` column.
`myfunc` gets the current row and has to extract `prev` and
`vals` from it, then return the result.

The only remaining thing is to drop `prev` column.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
import pandas as pd

def myfunc(x):
    pr = x.prev
    t1 = pr if pd.notnull(pr) else None
    t2 = x.vals
    return f'myfunc({repr(t1)}, {repr(t2)})'

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'vals':
    ['ANZ', 'ABC', 'SAT', 'SATYA', 'SQL', 'WER', 'DEA', 'KIP', 'FTY', 'TCZ'] })
df['prev'] = df.groupby('id').shift()
df['res'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
df.drop('prev', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

When you `print(df)`, you will get:

```
   id   vals                     res
0   1    ANZ     myfunc(None, 'ANZ')
1   1    ABC    myfunc('ANZ', 'ABC')
2   2    SAT     myfunc(None, 'SAT')
3   2  SATYA  myfunc('SAT', 'SATYA')
4   2    SQL  myfunc('SATYA', 'SQL')
5   3    WER     myfunc(None, 'WER')
6   3    DEA    myfunc('WER', 'DEA')
7   3    KIP    myfunc('DEA', 'KIP')
8   3    FTY    myfunc('KIP', 'FTY')
9   3    TCZ    myfunc('FTY', 'TCZ')
```